# I have no error when I run project with xampp, but have these error online

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I am beginner with Yii2,When I run my website by Xampp I don't have any errors, but after I uploaded it to a linux server I got this error:

> Non-static method frontend\controllers\SiteController::actionCategories() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

What is causing this?

```
 <?php
      $category_post = \frontend\controllers\SiteController::actionCategories($row['id']);
      echo ListView::widget([
           'dataProvider' => $category_post,
           'itemView' => 'news_title',
           'summary' => '',
           'pager' => [
                'options' => ['class' => 'row pagination '],
           ]
      ]);
 ?>
```

Comment: Seems there is problem in your path or routing. please check once. Please share your error message

Comment: no there is no problem in the path and routing

Comment: in your pinion is it possible that the problem is because of php version

Comment: Incorrect spelling has been corrected in your question. please approve.

Comment: Is there any difference in php version of your local and online server?

Comment: it was different,  now I changed linux php version to the same version in xampp, but nothing happened

Comment: just declare `actionCategories()` as `public static function actionCategories()` in model.

Comment: could you please vote may question? I'm question ban :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use

```
Yii::$app->controller->actionCategories($row['id']);
```

instead of

```
\frontend\controllers\SiteController::actionCategories($row['id']);
```

Comment: could you please vote may question? I'm question ban :-(